# Inserting random names PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How could I insert random names into another table ?
For example :

```
select firstname,lastname from table1;
create table2 (newfirstname varchar2(20),newlastname varchar2(20));
insert into table2 select newfirstname, random(newlastname);
```

How could I generate new people using table1's infos ?
So , my question is , how do I insert random "lastnames" from table1 into
table2 to obtain a new fullname(newfirstname+newlastname) from table2 being different of
(firstname+lastname) from table1.
I am using sql developer ,pl/sql .

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2
select A.firstname, B.lastname
  from table1 A, table1 B
 where not exists(select 1 from table1 C
                   where C.firstname=A.firstname and C.lastname=B.lastname)
```

Add random ordering and/or count limitation if need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have numeric ID field in table2, like table2.id, then

```
select  
(select MIN(table2.id) from table2) as minid, (select MAX(table2.id) from table2) as maxid, 
(select table2.firstname from table2 where table2.id >= dbms_random.value(minid,maxid) order by table2.id limit 1) as rnd_firstname, 
(select table2.lastname from table2 where table2.id >= dbms_random.value(minid,maxid) order by table2.id limit 1) as rnd_lastname;
```

will give you random combination of firstname + lastname from table2.

Comment: I get the point here, but I have to pick random lastnames from table1 and insert them into table2.Thus, I will have names in table2 that are different from table1.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT
    aa.nome,
    aa.sobrenome,
    bb.nome,
    bb.sobrenome,
    CASE 
        WHEN DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) > 20 THEN aa.nome || bb.sobrenome
        ELSE
         bb.nome || aa.sobrenome
    END AS new_name
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
          SubStr(b.nome,1,InStr(b.nome,' ')) nome,  
          SubStr(b.nome,InStr(b.nome,' '))  sobrenome,
          sexo
      FROM 
          cadastro b
      WHERE
          empresa_id=4 
      ORDER BY 
          DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,800000)
    ) aa,
    (
      SELECT 
          SubStr(b.nome,1,InStr(b.nome,' ')) nome,  
          SubStr(b.nome,InStr(b.nome,' '))  sobrenome,
          sexo
      FROM 
          cadastro b
      WHERE
          empresa_id=4               
      ORDER BY
        DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,800000 )
    ) bb
  WHERE  
      aa.sexo=bb.sexo
```